# Intermec printer stopped printing after sending IPL commands

Tags: php, printing, intermec, ipl

I tried printing a label to an Intermec printer from php using the following code:

```
    $cmds .= "<STX><ESC>C<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX><ESC>P<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>E4;F4;<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>H0;o102,51;f0;c25;h20;w20;d0,30;<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>L1;o102,102;f0;l575;w5;<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>B2;o203,153;c0,0;h100;w2;i1;d0,10;<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>I2;h1;w1;c20;<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>R;<ETX>";
    $cmds .= "<STX><ESC>E4<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX><CAN><ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>RO503C001IP0722RZ001-050<CR><ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX>RO503C001IP0722RZ001-050<ETX>"; 
    $cmds .= "<STX><ETB><ETX>";
$handle = printer_open("Intermec");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$cmds); 
printer_close($handle);
```

[This](http://intermec.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/416/~/another-sample-ipl-program) is the site from which I copied the Intermec Programming Language commands.

The script connected to the printer successfully but after running it, **the printer won't print anything, anything at all.** The Printer Monitor keeps showing Syntax Error.

Did I do something really wrong? Is there a way to make it print again?

I didn't have the inspiration to note down the printer type (I won't have access to it until tomorrow), but it looks exactly like the one in the picture below:

[image]

Please help me, I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Did you get an answer elsewhere?

For me, I use the following in place of your first 3 lines

```
<STX><ESC>P;E2;F2<ETX>
```

And for lines 8 to 10 I use

```
<STX>R<ESC>E2<CAN><ETX>
```

And in your last line I include `<FF>` after the `<ETB>`

Comment: Hi, Android  have any without Lineprintservice.apk sdk available?